# seeding a new replica set member with mongorestore is not recommended, why?

Tags: mongodb, replication, replicaset, mongodump

In [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/), I found the following statement:

> IMPORTANT Always use filesystem snapshots to create a copy of a member
>   of the existing replica set. Do not use mongodump and mongorestore to
>   seed a new replica set member.

1. what do I have to do if my FS does not support snapshots, and
2. **why** is this limitation here at all? Earlier, it was possible to use mongodump-generated snapshots to add new rs members (edit: if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: it looks like i was wrong. It was never possible to use mongodump-generated data to seed a RS member. If you attempt to do that - the instance will raise an error and do full-resync. Probably mongodump doesn't catch (even with oplog recording enabled) certain things needed to start replicating. For me, then, it's needed simply to let it do a full sync.